# Serve SPA from multiple Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

I'm developing a SPA with html5 routes. 
Ex: `https://app.example.com/restaurants/<restaurantId>/menu` etc

Basically the app creates dynamic websites for multiple restaurants, hosted at `https://app.example.com/restaurants/<restaurantId>`

The requirement is to allow the restaurant owners to host the site in their own domain name.

Ex: if the `restaurantId` of `Example Pizza Shop` is `xxx` 
then `www.examplepizza.com` should serve the contents of `https://app.example.com/restaurants/xxx` along with all the sub-routes.

The project is hosted on firebase, I'm looking for ideas on how to achieve this (even if I have to use services outside firebase it's okay)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is not well-suited to these kinds of multi-tenant use cases, and you'll find the same is true for most "platform-as-a-service" style hosting providers.

To host arbitrary custom domains, you'll need:

1. Dedicated IP addresses that customers can point their DNS providers to (A records).
2. A web server capable of dynamically changing what it serves based on the `Host` header of the incoming request.
3. An automated SSL certificate provisioning system to create certificates for each customer's custom domain.

This is generally a major undertaking and requires quite a bit of both general and specialized knowledge. I don't think Stack Overflow is going to be the right place to find a specific solution, but I hope this guides you on your journey.